# How to update a table due to case statement based on another table? (in Mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I have 2 tables:

TBL1

- STDNum
- ID
- Check

TBL2

- STDNum
- UpdateMe

the `STDNum` is the common column. In TBL1, the same STDNum can have multiple rows with different IDs (It's not the case on TBL2). *The result I wanted* is to **Update the `UpdateMe` Column in TBL2** (*setting its value to 1*) IF (*and only IF*) the `Check` *column in TBL1 for that Particular **STDNum is all set to 1***.

Can anybody please help me? or any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE  tbl2 b
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  STDNum
            FROM    tbl1 s
            GROUP   BY STDNum
            HAVING  MAX(s.check) = MIN(s.Check) AND
                    MAX(s.Check) = 1
        ) a ON a.STDNum = b.STDNum
SET     b.UpdateMe = 1
```

OR

```
UPDATE  tbl2 b
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  STDNum
            FROM    tbl1
            GROUP   BY STDNum
            HAVING  SUM(Check = 1) = COUNT(*)
        ) a ON a.STDNum = b.STDNum
SET     b.UpdateMe = 1
```

Comment: I am actually new to mysql and I kind of don't understand the b and the a you have included on your code. Are they just variables? Thanks.

Comment: `a` and `b` are called `ALIAS`. They are useful when you have longer table names. *If you happen ask me why did I chose `a` and `b` as their aliases, it's because I'm used to it.*